# Making more rigid a gooseneck

Tags: plumbing

I have a gooseneck which is closed on both ends. It's too flexible.

[image]

Any idea how I can make it more rigid? I have tried to circle it with tape but it's not so good. I was thinking to circle it with a shrinking heat tube and heat it up. But the tube will have to be very thick to add a lot of strength. Any other idea?

Comment: many ways .. pack with sand ... insert a wooden dowel ... insert heavy copper wire ... insert copper tube ... insert steel wire ... etc.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I should have been more precise. I cannot insert anything. It's closed on both ends...

Comment: Flat spring steel on the outside, with heatshrink tape or steampunk looking copper wire holding it on.

Comment: this may be an XY problem ... what is the actual problem that you are trying to solve by using a gooseneck

Answer (score 2):

One method that comes to mind is to wrap a suitably sized spring around the outside of the gooseneck. Springs are commonly used to perform tubing bends, restricting the expansion of the tubing to prevent kinking, but could be used in this instance to reduce the flexibility.

Tube bending springs are available from many sources. [This Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07W5MTTND) is only representative, not a recommendation.

[image: tube bending springs]
Image from linked Amazon site.

Note that the sizes available for springs may not match your application. It may be necessary to use an "ordinary" spring such as those found for screen door closings or similar.  The ad copy for the tube bending springs suggests to insert one spring inside the tube being bent and another on the outside, but for your situation, two (or more!) springs on the outside may also provide increased stiffness.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Insert a stiff wire like solid  #14awg.

Comment: OP says nothing can be inserted, it's closed on both ends.